# Maximum rolling sum in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to obtain the largest possible sum for a time period.

For example, I have a data frame with units in store for a certain product:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
    date = paste("Day", 1:5),
    units_in_store = c(10,3,-2,1,-1)
)
```

`cumsum(data$units_in_store)` would return 11 but the largest possible sum in that case is 13, and summing one by one the values would be 13, 11, 12 and 11.

*Is there a way to compute the maximum moving/rolling sum?*

In other words: *How can I compute the largest possible sum with*

*Day 1 + Day2*

*Day 1 + Day 2 + Day 3*

*Day 1 + Day 2 + Day 3 + Day 4*

*etc?*

This would be the expected output:

```
data %>% mutate(units2 = something(units_in_store))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  date  units_in_store units2
  <chr>          <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Day 1             10     13
2 Day 2              3     13
3 Day 3             -2     13
4 Day 4              1     13
5 Day 5             -1     13
```

Comment: Could you show your expected output?

Comment: sure! I did that

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
data<-mutate(data,units2=max(cumsum(units_in_store)))
```

output:

```
  date  units_in_store units2
  <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
1 Day 1             10    13
2 Day 2              3    13
3 Day 3             -2    13
4 Day 4              1    13
5 Day 5             -1    13
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Reduce`  to get the result "summing one by one":

```
> Reduce("+",data$units_in_store, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
[1] 13 11 12 11
```

This is an alternative to `cumsum` see @doviod´s answer. Then you can select the max value.